# Перенаправление с site1/site2/default.html на site2

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!

Мне необходимо на сервере запросы `http://site1/site2/default.htm` перенаправлять на `http://site2/` Я пробовала сделать так:

```
RewriteRule http://site1/site2/default.htm http://site2/
```

- не срабатывает. Весь файл:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$"> 
    ForceType text/html 
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule http://site1/site2/default.htm http://site2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Directory and htaccess context, the
> Pattern will initially be matched
> against the filesystem path, after
> removing the prefix that led the
> server to the current RewriteRule
> (e.g. "app1/index.html" or
> "index.html" depending on where the
> directives are defined).

То-есть если у вас .htaccess лежит в корне site1:

```
RewriteRule site2/default.htm http://site2/
```

[docs>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Или используя mod_alias:

```
Redirect /site2/default.htm http://site2/
```

[docs>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Comment: inso, спасибо, всё заработало